# javascript line break is not applying when i use document.execCommand("copy")

Tags: javascript

Hi i'm using below code to build a string and copying it,but in output when i paste it the line break is not applying

```
function copyToClipboardShipto() {
        var $temp = $("<input>");

        $("body").append($temp);
        var str1 = "@(Model.firstName)"; var str2 = " "; var str3 = "@(Model.lastName)"; var str4 = "\n";
        var str5 = "@(Model.shiptoes[0].address.address1)";
        var str6 = ",";
        var str7 = "@(Model.shiptoes[0].address.address2)";
        var str8 = "\n";
        var str9 = "@(Model.shiptoes[0].address.city)"; var str10 = ","; var str11 = "@(Model.shiptoes[0].address.state)"; var str12 = "\n";
        var str13 = "@(Model.shiptoes[0].address.zip)";
        var str = str1 + str2 + str3 + str4 + str5 + str6 + str7 + str8 + str9 + str10 + str11 + str12 + str13;
        $temp.val(str).select();
        document.execCommand("copy");
        $temp.remove();
    }
}
```

firstname lastname223 E JACKSON AVE,city,statezip 
any help appericiated

Comment: Could you paste  your code on fiddle

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `<textarea>` instead of `<input>`, since INPUT doesn't support multiline strings.

```
var $temp = $("<textarea>");
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `<textarea>` instead as `<input>` wont support line breaks.